# How React hook access closure variable

Tags: reactjs

When I tried the counter example in React with hooks, i want to see how async operation works in hooks, so I put code like:

```js
function App() {

  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  var times = count>0?"times":"time";
  var txt = count + " " + times;

useEffect(()=>{
  setTimeout(()=>{
    console.log(txt)
  }, 5000)
},[])

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Clicked {txt}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>{setCount(1+count);}}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

After the page load, I clicked the button several times and I see the count increased, but after 5 sec, the console still print out "0 time", I wonder why it does not access the txt variable value in the closure scope

Thanks.

```js
function App() {
  if(!window.stack) {
    window.stack = []
  }
  const [count, setCount] = useState({v:0});

  window.stack.push(count);
  var times = count.v>0?"times":"time";
  var txt = count.v + " " + times;

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Clicked {txt}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>{setCount({v:1+count.v});}}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Every time the component renders or re-renders, `App` runs again. Each re-render creates a new `count` variable.

The `useEffect` runs only on the initial render, since its dependency array is `[]`. On the initial render, `count` is `0`. If you click the button, the component will have re-rendered, but the timeout in the `useEffect` still closes over only the *initial render*'s `count` variable.

If you need something like this, you could use a ref as well, for which there is a stable reference across all renders, so the initial render's closure can reference the object that gets mutated in a later render:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);
  const times = count > 0 ? "times" : "time";
  const txt = count + " " + times;
  const txtRef = React.useRef(txt);
  txtRef.current = txt;

  React.useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log(txtRef.current);
    }, 5000)
  }, []);

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Clicked {txt}</h1>
      <button onClick={()=>{setCount(1+count);}}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector('.react'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div class='react'></div>
```

Another (probably worse, more complicated) option would be to call `clearTimeout` in `useEffect`'s cleanup, and call `setTimeout` on every render, pass the timeout time remaining from render to render by checking `Date.now()`. (this wouldn't work well for components that get frequently re-rendered)

Comment: thanks. I guess I am too new to react hooks to understand the explanation for useEffect, but if the App function runs several times, it should also mean the useEffect also gets run several times, why it only print out 0 times, I expect there should be server outputs

Comment: Since the dependency array is empty, the `useEffect` callback runs only on the first render. See the docs: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

Comment: Thanks. Another question is why it renders twice in my code initially without clicking (I also comment out the useEffect part)

Comment: It looks to only render once in my snippet? If you have React strict mode enabled, disable it

Comment: I add the code snippet at the bottom of my post, each time I push the count into window stack, and if I run that code, without clicking, the window.stack already has two entries both are count object with {value: 0}

Comment: When I paste it into my snippet here, the global array only contains one object. Again, make sure you aren't using React's strict mode.